# After rendering, the 'Crop' effect cuts off more than I chose

Tags: premiere

I use Adobe Premiere and I would like to crop some of clip. When I'm setting all on preview mode everything looks good, but after rendering more area is cut off.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Please add some information about what you're trying to accomplish, which crop effect you applied and preferably also some screenshots of the preview and the rendered output.

Comment: Have you done everything in between taking those screenshots except rendering the sequence? If not, have you tried turning it off an on again (i.e. Premiere, the PC and deleting the preview files)? Also, it would probably be of use if you could post a picture of the effect settings of the crop effect you applied as well. It would be interesting how the video looks after exporting the sequence as well